# How can I sort variables based on part of a string variable?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with string variables and I am trying to generate a new binary variable based on the first two characters. All strings are 5 characters long, but I'm only concerned with the first two in order to sort.

For example, I could have 22001 and 22005. Since both are of the form 22XXX, I want to assign value 1 for both in the variable type_A. And if I have 25001 and 25005, since both are not of the form 22XXX, I want to assign value 0 for both in the variable type_A.

Comment: @Nick You are not in favor of starting questions with 'In Stata, ...'?

Comment: It's site policy, I believe, not to name languages in titles. I can't find documentation for that, but (a) tags should be sufficient (b) keeping titles concise is important.

Comment: If as your question implies you want to sort on the first two characters, then `sort` will do that. It will sort on the other characters too, but you need not care about that. You don't need any new variable for that purpose. But perhaps your question isn't really about `sort` strict sense. It is not very clear either way.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
clear
set obs 4

generate str5 var1 = "22001" in 1
replace var1 = "22005" in 2
replace var1 = "25001" in 3
replace var1 = "25005" in 4

gen type_A = substr(var1, 1, 2) == "22"
```

Please note that as you explain your problem it looks like you you are storing `22005` as text - which may not necessarily be the best idea..